# How to Split a dataframe column that is a dictionary into two columns

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with a column such as

| ID | dictionary_column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {1:5, 10:15, 3:9} |
| 2 | {3:4, 5:3} |
| ... | ... |

and I'm trying to get it to look like:

| ID | col_a | col_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 10 | 15 |
| 1 | 3 | 9 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Any advice on this? Have used various methods using `stringr` but always lose track of the ID column or end up with messy and slow loops. Thanks

Comment: Kindly provide reproducible data by pasting the output from `dput(your_dataframe)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `str_extract_all` to extract the digits before and after the `:` into `list` columns and then `unnest` the `list`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(col_a = str_extract_all(dictionary_column, "\\d+(?=:)"),
       col_b = str_extract_all(dictionary_column, "(?<=:)\\d+"), 
       .keep = "unused") %>% 
    unnest(c(col_a, col_b))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
     ID col_a col_b
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1 1     5    
2     1 10    15   
3     1 3     9    
4     2 3     4    
5     2 5     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, dictionary_column = c("{1:5, 10:15, 3:9}", 
"{3:4, 5:3}")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` approach to achieve your desired result may look like so:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data.frame(
  ID = c(1L, 2L),
  dictionary_column = c("{1:5, 10:15, 3:9}", "{3:4, 5:3}")
) %>%
  mutate(dictionary_column = gsub("(\\{|\\})", "", dictionary_column)) %>%
  separate_rows(dictionary_column, sep = ", ") %>%
  separate(dictionary_column, into = c("col_a", "col_b"))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>      ID col_a col_b
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 1     5    
#> 2     1 10    15   
#> 3     1 3     9    
#> 4     2 3     4    
#> 5     2 5     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant but it works:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  mutate(dictionary_column = gsub("\\{|\\}|\\,", "", dictionary_column)) %>% 
  separate(dictionary_column, into=c("a", "b", "c"), sep=" ") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID, values_drop_na=T) %>% 
  select(-name) %>% 
  separate(value, into = c("col_a", "col_b"))
```

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
     ID col_a col_b
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1 1     5    
2     1 10    15   
3     1 3     9    
4     2 3     4    
5     2 5     3
```